# ASP.NET solution stored in a remote webserver. How to debugg?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, remote-debugging

I'm working in a website using ASP.NET MVC3 framework. 
At the moment I've moved the solution to the remote server and since then i've been working at it using my host computer and It's VStudio 2010 IDE. I've just needed to establish a VPN connection and everything went fine, i'm even able to build the solution remotely by doing build > rebuild solution. The problem is that the default debugger from Visual Studio runs on localhost and the solution which i'm working on it's on the remote server.

So how can i set up a remote debugging of this solution/project?

Hopefuly someone knows how to help me.

Comment: Don't develop on a web server. Develop locally and then deploy to the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this guide:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio